# Put request 403 error django restframework

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am creating a web application with react-js using redux and back-end with python django with django rest framework.

for authentication I am using JWT.

The problem I am facing is when sending request from front-end getting error as 403.

I have checked the backend side all the configuration are set but still getting this error.

Please check the below code.

Model:

```
class StatusQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    pass

class StatusManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return StatusQuerySet(self.model,using=self._db)

class Apptype(models.Model):
    user        =   models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    appType     =   models.CharField(max_length=50)
    objects     =   StatusManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.appType
```

Serializer:

```
class AppTypeSeriializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Apptype
        fields = [
            'user',
            'id',
            'appType'
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['user','id']
```

views

```
class AppTypeStatusAPIDetailView(
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
    generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    lookup_field            =   'id'
    permission_classes      =   [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    serializer_class        =   AppTypeSeriializer
    queryset                =   Apptype.objects.all()


    def put(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Value of = ",request.data.get("appType"))
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def patch(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def delete(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

URL

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^appType/$',AppTypeStatusView.as_view()),
    url(r'^appType/(?P<id>\d+)/$',AppTypeStatusAPIDetailView.as_view()),
 ]
```

Permissions

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),

    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,
}
```

Front-end code when action triggers.

```
export const updateAppTypeData = (appData) => async dispatch => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  console.log(token)

  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "JWT "+ token,
  }
  const data =  {"appType":"Kilo"} // Custom send
  const response = await axios.put('http://localhost:8000/api/posts/appType/1/',JSON.stringify(data),headers)
  //dispatch({ type : FETCH_APP_TYPE , payload: response.data });
};
```

Error :

[image]

Comment: Check the request headers for the request in the `Network` tab of your browser.

Comment: @ja6fa7jq Did you try it with REST tools like **POSTMAN**?

Comment: Thanks @Sachin you comment and answer helped me.

The token is getting expired and I was sending the expired token again and again also way of sending the request was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the [axios.put](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosputurl-data-config) method wrong.
You need to pass the config containing a key named `headers` in it. You are currently passing headers directly as the third argument.

**Solution**:

```
axios.put(
  'http://localhost:8000/api/posts/appType/1/',
  JSON.stringify(data),
  {
      headers: headers
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sachin. I was struggling from 2 days for this. It was great help from you.

Answer (score 0):

This setup works for me,

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (  
       'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication', 
       'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
       'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',

   ),
```

and `View` with `authentication_classes`, authentication_classes should be tupple, so if you use one authentication class make sure to use "," at the end  authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

```
class MainPollVoteByUser(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = MainPollVoteSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly, IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,SessionAuthentication)
```